# How to iterate through an ActiveRecord column list and replace text?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I noticed that my text editor has inserted several weird characters that need to be replaced. I have about 13 records with maybe 6-7 columns each that contain text which needs to have this character replaced. Here's what I did to come up with an option:

```
Assessment.find(1039).issues.each do |issue|
  issue.attributes.each do |attribute|
    issue.attributes.keys.each do |key|
      if issue.attributes[key].to_s.include? "\u2019"
        issue.update(key, issue.attributes[key].gsub("\u2019", "'"))
      end
    end
  end
end
```

However, this doesn't work as I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
        6: from (irb):212
        5: from (irb):213:in `block in irb_binding'
        4: from (irb):213:in `each'
        3: from (irb):214:in `block (2 levels) in irb_binding'
        2: from (irb):214:in `each'
        1: from (irb):216:in `block (3 levels) in irb_binding'
ArgumentError (wrong number of arguments (given 2, expected 1))
```

How would I accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`ActiveRecord::Persistence#update`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Persistence.html#method-i-update) receives a single argument, which is a hash containing the keys (columns) and values (update values) to use in the UPDATE statement.

Try instead:

```
issue.update(key => issue.attributes[key].gsub("\u2019", "'"))
```

I could recommend you to get every Issue by their `assesment_id` (if exists) and then `find_each` perhaps, if the number of records is big enough.